# Blurress in Safari with 3d CSS transformation and scaling

Tags: css, safari, css-transforms

For some reason, if you add transform: translateZ(0) for parent or offspring, you get blurriness on safari

```
<div class="scene"><div class="d1">Test safari scale</div></div>

.scene, .d1
  position: absolute
  
.scene
  transform-origin: 0 0
  transform: translateX(0px) translateY(0px) scale(20)
.d1 
  width: 200px
  height: 200px
  background-color: #d8afaf
  border: 2px solid grey
  transform: translateZ(0)
```

Working example: https://codepen.io/onopich/pen/XWgeGmy

If you add transform: translateZ(0) to .scene or to .d1, the problem is there. Screenshot on Safari and on Chrome in comparison:

[link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tb67X.jpg)

Comment: Could you please provide the safari version you're using? This would help a lot :) -> https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I tested this on several versions: 15, 14, 13...